# Is it possible to deploy custom TFS 2013 Web Access extensions using an installer?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013

As far as I know, if you develop a Team Foundation Server 2012/2013 Web Access extension, you need to deploy them using the Web GUI.

Is it possible to deploy using an installer?

For example, maybe there's some TFS REST API resource which supports uploading a ZIP package.

Comment: I wouldn't expect much, the extension API (as I'm sure you know) is basically undocumented.

Comment: @DanielMann You're right, this is why I came here to ask this question. Who knows if it comes some TFS developer on Microsoft and gives some light to issues like my question! :)

Comment: Try running Fiddler when you upload an extension, see if it's something you can reverse engineer.

Comment: @DanielMann It's a good idea!

Comment: @DanielMann I've checked that, there's an AJAX call but its very coupled with the client-side browser code.